# TableViewCell color issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios7

I set background color to table view. Color has 30% transparency. Issue is that part of the table where there is no cell, color is displayed with transparency set. But cell is displayed with no transparency.

I don't set color in code. Table background color is set in storyboard. Please ask for any other information required.

[image]

**Table in storyboard :**

[image]

**Code :**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Set cell content
    cell.NameLabel.text = ...;
    cell.SequenceLabel.text = ...;
    cell.NumberLabel.text = ...;

    cell.backgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor; // Also tried setting to [UIColor clearColor]

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Do you want cells to be displayed WITH transparency?

Comment: @Avt Yes, cell should have same color with same alpha value.

Comment: @FahimParkar There is nothing to show in code. Code simply sets label values. Without reuse identifier how will it work? Its custom cell.

Comment: set color for cell.contentView.

Answer (score 3):

set the background color of the cell same as tableview background color with same transperancy, and set the tableview background color as clear color.
I hope, this will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Try using the below code & put your own RDB values :

```
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:2.0f blue:85.0f alpha:0.3f];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting transparency on the table view but the cells' views are not transparent. Just set the background color of each cell to transparent.

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

or set it to the same color the table view is

```
cell.backgroundColor = self.tableView.backgroundColor;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set cell's background clearcolor as well or if you are setting a background image of each cell than you have to use that transparent image and also set alpha of that image 0.3 so it will be transparent.

```
cell.backGroundColor=[UiColor ClearColor];
```

or you have to set alpha of your cell's backGround Color

```
    cell.imageView.alpha=0.3;
```

Comment: I don't use background image to cell.

Comment: than i think cell.backgroundcolor=[uicolor clearcolor] must work atleast worked in my application

Comment: That did not work. I already tried that as suggested by `reecon`. Please see updated question. I added an image